# How to set an image to the really top of app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

i try to set an image to the very top of my android app.

But there is always space to the left/right/top even if margin is zero.

code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/bgColor"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Where is my error?
Thanks =)

Comment: You have padding in your layout which will add space around it by `@dimen/activity_vertical_margin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your *dimens.xml* file (res/values directory) for the `activity_vertical_margin` and `activity_horizontal_margin` `dimen` resources. You are using those for your parent `RelativeLayout` as padding:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```